# Setup wordpress as subpath but in different root

Tags: nginx, php, wordpress

Main site: `example.com` in `/var/www/example.com`.

Wordpress blog: `example.com/blog` in `/var/www/blog`.

Can't make it work.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index Index.html index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|json|txt|sd|html)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            access_log off;
            expires 1d;
    }

    location ~* \.(js)$ {
        gzip_static on;
        gunzip on;
        try_files $uri =404;
        access_log off;
        expires 1d;
    }


    location /blog {
        alias  /var/www/blog/;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @blog;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
            try_files $uri =404;
            include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            #fastcgi_index index.php;

             #include the fastcgi_param setting
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location @blog {
            rewrite ^/blog(.*) /blog/index.php?q=$1;
    }
}
```

For `http://example.com/blog` got `403 Forbidden`. Looks like `alias` doesn't work with `try_files`.

But even `http://example.com/blog/index.php` doesn't work. Got `File not found.` .

Comment: I think this is common in the WordPress tutorials I've seen: `location try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;`.

Comment: @Paul it's for case when blog is in subdirectory.

Comment: Remove the subdirectory: `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; }`

Comment: Replace `alias` with `root /var/www;` and use `try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;`

Comment: @RichardSmith `try_files` doesn't work in this case for `http://example.com/blog`: `directory index of "/var/www/blog/" is forbidden`. But `http://example.com/blog/index.php` works.

Comment: You haven't added `index.php` to your `index` directive, so its looking for `index.html` and not finding it. Alternatively, you could place an `index index.php;` statement in the `location /blog` block